# Can't install new sotware in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the WindowBuilder for Eclipse, but when I go to `Help -> Install New Sotware` i get this `Cannot complete the request.This Installation had not been configured properly for software update. see the error log`
In the error log I get this `Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.`

Can anyone help me confire it so that I can install the plugin?

Comment: try installing through Eclipse marketplace

Answer (score -1):

You can also install manually without eclipse.
Do the following:

1. download the plugin file.
2. notice that within the compressed file there are 2 folders:
   plugin and features.
3. Now, open your eclipse directory (e.g. C:\eclipseKepler)
   Notice that there are plugin and features folders as well.
4. drop the content of the plugin folder of your plugin into C:\eclipseKepler\plugins
5. drop the feature's folder content into C:\eclipseKepler\features
6. finally launch eclipse.

This should work

Comment: Not the direct answer and not a recommended way to install plug-ins.